# Selenium Java: errorRecovery

Tags: java, exception-handling, selenium

I have the following code to select an image using Selenium, only now I have added an `errorRecovery`.  Is there is a better way to right the code in the `catch`?

```
    public static void selectHeader() {
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
                .xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'picture-und-0-select')]")));
        driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("//a[contains(@id, 'picture-und-0-select')]"))
                .click();
        driver.switchTo().frame("mediaBrowser");
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By
                .linkText("LIBRARY")));
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("LIBRARY")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.tagName("img")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Submit")).click();
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    } catch (UnhandledAlertException alert) {
        errorRecovery error = _TestSuite.errorRecovery;
        if (error.getCount() == 0) {
            error.addCount();
            selectHeader();
        } else {
            error.resetCount();
            throw new UnhandledAlertException(alert.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Judging by the overall structure it looks quite good, I would change a few things though with respect to formatting:

1. Your `public static void selectHeader() {` line seems to be off, might've been due to putting the code here, you should remove 4 blanks.
2. Take as example this line:

   ```
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
          .xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'picture-und-0-select')]")));
   ```

   I think it would read better as:

   ```
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
          By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'picture-und-0-select')]")));
   ```

   Note that now every argument is on one line.
3. Similar situations a few lines below.

Then onto the exception handling:

1. First I would change `UnhandledAlertException alert` to `UnhandledAlertException alertEx`, to denote that it is about an exception.
2. `errorRecovery error = _TestSuite.errorRecovery` confuses me to no ends, hence these suggestions:

   - `_TestSuite` should not have the underscore in front of it, I am still assuming it is a class though.
   - `errorRecovery` appears to be a class, which **really should and needs to be** upper-cased to prevent any confusion I had so far.
3. Your `header_afbeelding_selecteer()` method call is in Dutch and not in camelCase, it should be something like `headerImageSelect()`.
4. Lastly, your `ErrorRecovery error` is **not** an error, it is an `recovery` or an `errorRecovery`, please name your variable like that.

I do not fully get what your error handling code does though, there also seems to be logic ongoing which is not neccessary, all I see that you are really using is the method call to `headerImageSelect()`.

Therefore I suggest to add the following to your `ErrorRecovery` class:

```
public void handleRecovery(final Runnable methodToRun, final String exceptionMessage) throws UnhandledAlertException {
    if (getCount() == 0) {
        addCount();
        methodToRun.run();
    }
    else {
        resetCount();
        throw new UnhandledAletException(exceptionMessage);
    }
}
```

Which can then be called as:

```
errorRecovery.handleRecovery(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        headerImageSelect();
    }, alertEx.toString());
```

Or if you are using Java 8, just:

```
errorRecovery.handleRecovery(() -> headerImageSelect(), alertEx.toString());
```

or even better:

```
errorRecovery.handleRecovery(this::headerImageSelect, alertEx.toString());
```

The design still seems weird to me though, which perhaps now is even more obvious, why does your error recovery method throw an `UnhandledAlertException`? Indicating that your error would need recovery again!

Comment: the browser used by Selenium sometimes throws a random pop-up after wich an UnhandledAlertException is thrown, what I want do with this errorRecovery is that when the exception occurs the method is run again and if that also fails, that only then an error will be given.